# How to do 1-1 to one fuzzy string matching between two huge lists of strings in most efficient/fastest way?

Tags: python, algorithm

For instance:

```
Table1_Attribute
ABC COMPANY
DEF COMPANY
CUROFY

Table2_Attribute
ABC INC
DEF
```

My intention is to generate a table as follows:

```
Table1_Attribute    Table2_Attribute    ratio
  ABC COMPANY          ABC INC          0.55
  DEF COMPANY            DEF            0.43
  CUROFY                  -              -
```

Comment: Do you want to end up with a 1:1 matching or do you want to compute the ratio for every possible matching?

Comment: just 1:1 matching. actually in my case, the length of two lists is not equal which i have not mentioned here. sorry that I did not clarify.Thanks

Comment: The problem you describe has two parts: (1) calculate pairwise string similarites/distances (2) compute a 1:1 matching. Which part do you have problems with?

Comment: 1st part is my priority,sir!

Comment: Then you probably want to select a proper [string metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric). The most prominent one being [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: I tried but it is not faster .One list contains 4 lakh strings and other contains 15 lakh around. I need some solution like set intersection which is lot faster but it only do exact string matching. I want to fuzzy-matching-stuff to take into account. need help

Comment: Not faster than what? So far it is not clear if you are looking for an improvement in speed or accuracy. It would be good if you could state what you have done so far and where you would like to improve.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned "fastest way". so I want speed. It's taking a day longer. Could you help me with how to implement Trie with regex? or any better source you if you have!

Comment: The problem is your question is underspecified. Given a String distance we can try to optimize it for two large sets of strings. However, if you only care about speed and not about accuracy, we can define a string distance (e.g., lexicograhically close) that can be computed quickly but does not output meaningful results.

Comment: @subhendu speed will usually be at the cost of accuracy. You don't define what accuracy means (what is a "fuzzy match", what is not a match?) so it's practicallyimpossible to pick a algorithm + say it's the "fastest" for your purposes.